# MongoDB import/ export using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to perform import and export operation in MongoDB using Node.js? The code which we use in MongoDB for this is

```
mongoimport --collection Newimport --file filename.json
mongoexport --db test --collection CollectionName --out outputFileName.json
```

I need to perform this using Node.js

Comment: Off-topic for this board - not a programming question.  (Not your downvoter, just explaining why...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to create Child process in NodeJS and try execute `mongoimport` or `mongoexport` commands

More on this on following links :

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn