# Compose two Docker image into one : NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to make new Docker image which contains NodeJS and MongoDB. 
I have a nodeJS(latest) image. 
Dockerfile is

```
FROM node

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb

EXPOSE 8800 
EXPORT 27017
```

If I build it, It is not working on two port(mongodb:27017, nodeJS:8800).
Do I need to make Dockerfile on ubuntu Image, not a node Image?

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

Comment: Per your comments in Mohsen's answer, may I suggest `nodejs + 3rd party libs` as architecture and therefore question title?

Comment: @qarma sure. what libs are you gonna suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to run `node` server along side with `Mongo`? this is wrong in so many levels!

But if you want to use `node` image just for as your base image and don't need anything from node, then go with it! but it would be better to use `ubuntu` image because it takes much less space!

Comment: My nodeJS app need to use "mongoimport" shell command which is only used in mongodb container.. So I want to install mongodb on node image

Comment: so install `mongo-cli` on your node container! you don't need mongod for this matter!

Comment: mongo-client doesn't have 'mongoimport' command... To use this command in nodeJS, I can create child-process => http://stackoverflow.com/q/27813783/6810726 . So mongodb and nodejs container should be same.

Comment: As you can see in [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--host), you don't need to run it in the same server!
run it with `--host` option! and let docker take care of the network thing!

Comment: You mean, connect nodeJS(8800) port to mongodb port(27017)? nodeJS container doesn't have mongoimport shell command.

Comment: first of all you need to install `mongodb-org-tools` in order to get mongoimport on your nodejs! after that, you should link your mongo container to nodjes container! then do as you wish!

Comment: But regarding to usage of `mongoimport`, why do you need it? are you going to do importing a lot? what are your alternative options?

Comment: Yes. Each data would be around 800MB. When use nodejs mongo client to import that data(reading, parsing...) It takes +30minutes but mongoimport command takes just 1min. I can not find mongoimport in nodejs mongodb-org-tools ..